# How to create a maven repository that others may use?

Tags: jar, maven-3

I have a project that is hosted on github. Now what I want is that just by including a few lines like these, anyone is able to use my library in their maven project.

```
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.anahata</groupId>
>       <artifactId>anahata-core</artifactId>
>       <version>1.0</version>    
     </dependency>
```

I am new to maven, so please tell me the exact steps. Can it be hosted from github itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your project hosted in the Maven Central Repository following the tips posted [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html), [here](http://jroller.com/holy/entry/releasing_a_project_to_maven) and [here](http://wiki.ivonet.nl/display/JAVA/Get+you+maven+project+into+the+Maven+Central+Repository). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280470/maven-repository-for-google-code-project) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662546/how-to-deploy-my-open-source-projects-using-mavens-central-repository).

Edit: Also [Sonatype's guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) as suggested by khmarbaise (it is referred to by the guides above).

Answer (score 1):

Not to miss the guide of Sonatype:

https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide